# How to find css files with regex

Tags: php, regex

I need to find all the css references in a piece of code with regex

Suppose I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
```

The result of the match should be `mystyle.css` 
For now I only have `~href=\'.*\.css.*\'~` which matches the entire reference so it's not ok.

Comment: Better use DOM not regex

Comment: Why do you need to use a regex for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Karthik's answer is "almost" correct.

I made a "little" change in his [example](https://regex101.com/r/kW8qS1/7), which now also catches urls like:

```
http://blah.com/style.css
```

Modified regex is as follows:

```
~(?<=href=")[^"]+\.css~
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
~(?<=href=")[^."]+\.css~
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kW8qS1/6)

Answer (score 0):

There is no good reason to use a regex for this. Read in the HTML file as a DOM document, and extract the stylesheet references with Xpath:

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("test.html");

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$stylesheets = $xpath->query("//link[@rel='stylesheet']/@href");

if ($stylesheets->length == 0) {
    echo "nothing found!\n";
} else {
    foreach ($stylesheets as $stylesheet) {
        echo "found stylesheet: " . $stylesheet->nodeValue . "\n";
    }
}

?>
```

That is, for each `link` element in the document (the `//link` part) where the `rel` property is `stylesheet` (`[@rel='stylesheet']`), extract the `href` attribute (`/@href`).